# Why does bootstrap both needs the class name and the Id name for collapse?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap when you do collapse effect as below:

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-block">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

why would the buttons refer to the class `data-toggle=collapse` and the id `data-target=#collapseExample` of the panel for the effect? Wouldnt just getting the ID sufficient enough to toggle its state?

is it because data-toggle refers to what kind of effect its going to use therefore targets the panel with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes are used because `data-toggle` is also used by other Bootstrap components (ie; collapse, modal, tab, dropdown, etc..).

By specifying `data-toggle="collapse"` you're telling the Bootstrap API to apply the Collapse behavior to the element specified by `data-target`. If you only specified `data-target` there's no way for the API to understand which [Component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) is to be used.

Comment: Thank you very much! It got me confused because the class name is also named `collapse`, I ended up assuming it was targeting the class name as well.